# how to run onLongClick Event continously?

Tags: android, button, onclick, forward

Is it possible to implement a fast forward button using the onLongClick button event?

**EDIT**

> i used runnable inside the onlongclicklistner and adding the code for reference who needs :)

```
   Button.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {


            final Runnable r = new Runnable()
            {
                public void run() 
                {//do the forwarding logic here


                     if(Button.isPressed()){

                            Button.postDelayed(this, 1000); //delayed for 1 sec
                        }else{

                        Button.postInvalidate();
                        Button.invalidate();
                        }
                }
            };

            Button.post(r);

            return true;
            }
    });
```

Comment: Do you mean you want it to begin fast-forwarding when you long-click, and continue doing so until you release the button?

Comment: This might be of help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7124920/how-to-detect-onlongclick-action-up-event

Answer (score 2):

1. In your `onLongClick` event, set a member variable (example: `mShouldFastForward`) to `true`.
2. In the rest of your code (perhaps each frame played?) check if `mShouldFastForward == true`; if so, perform a fast-forward on that frame.
3. Use an `onTouch` event to capture the `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` to set `mShouldFastForward` to `false`.

Comment: the rest of your code part, where will you keep that??? since the activity work for events right???

Comment: Wherever your play code is. In whatever loop or event runs the playing video. Or, worst case, on a timer.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it in this project (the project is not finished (ie polished) but fast forward works):

https://bitbucket.org/owentech/epileptic-gibbon-android

Take a look at playerfragment.java :

I handle this by using Threads to fast forward the mediaplayer.

Example code from project:

```
/*******************************/
/* Fast-Forward button actions */
/*******************************/

ffbutton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) {

   switch (event.getAction() ) { 

       case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: 

           arrays.fastforwardpressed = true;
           FastForwardThread newFFThread = new FastForwardThread();
           arrays.fastforwardfrom = mp.getCurrentPosition();
           arrays.fastforwardto = arrays.fastforwardfrom;

           newFFThread.start();
           break;

       case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

           arrays.fastforwardpressed = false;
           mp.seekTo(arrays.fastforwardto);
           break; 

    }

    return true;
  }
});


public class FastForwardThread extends Thread
{
    public FastForwardThread()
    {
        super("FastForwardThread");
    }

    public void run()
    {
        while (arrays.fastforwardpressed == true)
        {

            arrays.fastforwardto = arrays.fastforwardto + 10000;
            int fastforwardseconds = arrays.fastforwardto / 1000;
            int hours = fastforwardseconds / 3600, remainder = fastforwardseconds % 3600, minutes = remainder / 60, seconds = remainder % 60;

            String Hours = Integer.toString(hours);
            String Minutes = Integer.toString(minutes);
            String Seconds = Integer.toString(seconds);

            if (Hours.length() == 1)
            {
                Hours = "0" + Hours;
            }

            if (Minutes.length() == 1)
            {
                Minutes = "0" + Minutes;
            }

            if (Seconds.length() == 1)
            {
                Seconds = "0" + Seconds;
            }

            arrays.formattedfftime = Hours + ":" + Minutes + ":" + Seconds;

            fastforwardHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);

            try
            {
                sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: i want continue play video in fastforward, how i can do that, can you help me please?