# Android button onLongClick, how to get the listener when the button is released from a long click

Tags: android, button, record, onlongclicklistener

I'm following [this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/audio-capture.html) to implement a recorder in Android, which contains the code below, when the button is held, start recording, when released, stop recording, but I can't find the listener when the button is released, any advice? Thank you in advance

```
button.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {          
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View arg0) {
            startRecording();
            return false;
        }           
    });

private void startRecording() {
    mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    mRecorder.setOutputFile(voiceFileName);
    mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    try {
        mRecorder.prepare();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");
    }
    mRecorder.start();
}

private void stopRecording() {
    mRecorder.stop();
    mRecorder.release();
    mRecorder = null;
}
```

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7124920/how-to-detect-onlongclick-action-up-event) thread

Comment: Thanks, I should use setOnTouchListener instead of setOnClickListener to detect the motion of the button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't implement the longclicklistener, you should implement the OnTouchListener.

There you will have the touch event, and do this:

```
button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){

            stopRecording();
            return true;
        }else{
            startRecording();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Minor correction, the "return false" here is unreachable, thus throws a compiler error.

Answer (score 0):

the boolean value "start" controls it

```
 private void onRecord(boolean start) {
        if (start) {
            startRecording();
        } else {
            stopRecording();
        }
    }
```

and then

```
 class RecordButton extends Button {
        boolean mStartRecording = true;

        OnClickListener clicker = new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onRecord(mStartRecording);
                if (mStartRecording) {
                    setText("Stop recording");
                } else {
                    setText("Start recording");
                }
                mStartRecording = !mStartRecording;
            }
        };
```

controls it

Comment: Thank you, the logic above is correct, but I want to detect whether the long click, use setOnTouchListener works.